# Regex for phone number with specific country code

Tags: typescript

I want to write a regex for a specific country code and number

```
 const regexpwithCountryCode = new RegExp('^\\+(48)[0-9]{9}$');
       
 console.log( regexpwithCountryCode.test(String(+48124223232)) );
```

I basically want to validate such string above as correct, my regex should accept number with + in the begining and 48 then 9 digits.

I am using https://regex101.com/ to test and it says its correct but when i use it in angualar with typescipt i get console output false

what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: Why do you have a capture group around 48?  Why are you using `RegExp` instead of using a simpler regex literal?

Comment: `String(+48124223232)` takes the number (+48124223232) and turn it into a string. Because +48124223232 is the same number as 48124223232, it will remove the plus for you. You shouldn't give it a number, you should give it a string directly, ie `...test("+48124223232")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put it into a string like this:

```js
const regexpwithCountryCode = /^\+48[0-9]{9}$/;

console.log(regexpwithCountryCode.test("+48124223232"));
```